# How to access and configure postgresql database from python django on Windows 7 using a command CMD

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

When I run a CMD Windows 7 command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

I get an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available database backend. Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX' where XXX is one of : 'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'
```

I have installed postgresql 10, and in my django `setting.py` I have set the postgresql as [per the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/databases/)

I want to access postgresql database from python django app using CMD on Windows 7.

I'm using Windows 7, python 3.7.1; postgresql 10; django 2.1.5. I've tried several searches for solution but I do not get a relevant solution. I have already created my postgresql database using pgAdmin 4 v4 but it fails to be accessed using CMD command on Windows 7 to do commands like:

```
python manage.py showmigrations/makemigrations/migrate
```

all sends the same error as presented in the subject.

## settings.py file starts here...

```
"""
Django settings for my_sample project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'secret key string was here but now is purposely removed'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'my_sample.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_sample.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_sample',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_password',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

#settings.py file ends here...

#manage.py file starts here...

#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_sample.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

#manage.py file ends here...
```

When I run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I expect to get:

```
Running migrations: 
No migrations to apply.
```

Instead, I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available database backend. Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX' where XXX is one of : 'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the psycopg2 package? See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/install/#database-installation.

Or run `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: Yes, I installed psycopg2 through "pip install psycopg2"

Comment: if it complains on the engine value the error should be 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' and not 'django.db.backends.postgresql'. The solution might lie in this field. try typing it by hand to avoid encoding errors.

Comment: I have tried deleting and retyping it as 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2' but still sends the error 'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available database backend. Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX' where XXX is one of : 'mysql', 'oracle', 'sqlite3'

Comment: The first error that preceded the statement "The above exception was the direct cause of the following exceptions: .........." is " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.db.backends.postgresql' ". It seems it reported this principal error after checking the file "...\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py, line 110 in load_backend" and then file " ...\lib\importlib\\__init__.py, line 127 in import_module"

Answer (score 0):

Add your app inside the INSTALLED_APPS list as below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'yoursampleapp'
]
```

And then run makemigrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Comment: I have added my app 'my_sample' saved the setting.py file and re-run the python manage.py makemigrations command from cmd Windows 7 but I still get the same error.